# Image mover with javascript does not work properly

Tags: javascript, image, listener, mouse, mouselistener

Because of an oversized image I want to make it scrollable in the browser window. Scrolling should work in two ways: a) via scroll bars and b) by mouse action. The latter one should work like dragging the image in the direction wanted. So I built a script and attached it to the image. Although the code looks correct it does not work properly. The image sometimes disappears or jumps to an unwanted position. You can invoke the script under

http://ardent.de/JS/

and the code is attached. Does anybody know the reason for the image jumping or disappearing? I'd be glad to receive an answer.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>        
        <body>
        <img src="schloss.jpg" id="image" />

        <script>
        var div=document.getElementById('image');
        var iwidth,iheight,oldY,oldX,newX, newY;
        var mouseisdown=false;

        div.addEventListener('load', function() {
        iwidth=this.naturalWidth;
        iheight=this.naturalHeight;
        });

        function getCoordinates(elem) {
        var LeftPos = elem.offsetLeft;
        var TopPos = elem.offsetTop;
        return {X:LeftPos,Y:TopPos};
        }

        function addListeners() {
        div.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        div.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, false);
        var p=getCoordinates(div);oldX = p.X;oldY = p.Y;
        }

        function mouseUp() {
        mouseisdown=false;
        }

        function mouseDown() {
        mouseisdown=true;
        }   

        function divMove(e){
        if (mouseisdown) {
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        newY=e.clientY-oldY;
        newX=e.clientX-oldX;
        div.style.top = newY + 'px';
        div.style.left = newX + 'px';
        oldY=newY;
        oldX=newX;}
        }

        addListeners();

      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic is incorrect:

```
newY=e.clientY-oldY;
newX=e.clientX-oldX;
...
oldY=newY;
oldX=newX;
```

Let say your `oldX` is 0 at start. `e.clientX` may be 1920 in a full hd screen.

`newX` value could be jumping from 0 to 1920 because:

```
newX=e.clientX-oldX; // 1920 - 0
oldX=newX; // 1920
... // Next tick
newX = e.clientX - oldX; // 1920 - 1920
oldX=newX; // 0
```

So basically this is why the image is jumping from two odd positions.

Comment: OK, I corrected the code, but it still does Work properly. Holding down the mouse and moving the image does not work - I have to click the mouse beforehand and move it afterwards.

Comment: @JensD, if you corrected your code, you may want to either mark this as the correct answer or provide a better answer yourself.

Comment: @lilizek thank you for the first analysis, which was very helpful. I'll be back with a better code later on.

Answer (score 0):

This is now the improved code. The usage of global variables has been reduced and only two, oldX/Y, remain. My first logical error with the positioning has been corrected. The other problem was the drag behavior of the image, which inhibited the mouseup event. So I set draggable to false and now it works fine in the Chrome browser. Also I had to consider the order of img... and script... which is crucial sometimes, if there is a reference between both tags. Now look at http://ardent.de/JS/ and move the image by pressing the mouse button and moving the mouse.

```
      <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      </head>
        <body>
        <div  id="image" onmousedown="mouseDown();" onmouseup="mouseUp();">
          <img src="schloss.jpg" draggable="false" />
        </div>

        <script>
        var oldY,oldX;

        function getCoordinates(elem) {
          var LeftPos = elem.offsetLeft;
          var TopPos = elem.offsetTop;
          return {X:LeftPos,Y:TopPos};
        }

        function mouseUp() {
          document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
          document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
         }

        function mouseDown() {
         document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
         document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
         oldY=-1; oldX=-1;
        }   

        function mouseMove(e){
          var iwidth,iheight,newX, newY, diffX, diffY;
          var div=document.getElementById('image');        
          div.style.position = 'absolute';
          if (oldX==-1) {
            diffX=0;diffY=0;}
          else {
            diffY=e.clientY-oldY;diffX=e.clientX-oldX;}
          var p=getCoordinates(div);
          newY=p.Y+diffY;newX=p.X+diffX;
          div.style.top = newY + 'px';div.style.left = newX + 'px';
          oldY=e.clientY;oldX=e.clientX;
          }

      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```